# Is the score breakdown feature employed only in Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I just found out this groovy feature in Ask Ubuntu, if I click on the score of a question or answer it shows the score breakdown (the number of upvotes and downvotes). For example, for this question titled [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages), it shows the following.
[image]

But to my surprise I couldn't find this feature in **any** of the popular Stack Exchange sites listed below.

- Stack Overflow
- Super User
- Server Fault
- Stack Overflow in Russian
- TeX - LaTeX
- Unix & Linux
- Cross Validated
- Physics
- Mathematics
- English Language & Usage
- English Language Learners

**Disclaimer:** I opened all those sites except Stack Overflow and English Language & Usage as visitors (didn't log in). Also I have very little reputation in those two sites. If this feature depends on the user reputation this question is meaningless.

Is this something special to Ask Ubuntu? If so, is there any particular reason why others didn't employ it?

Comment: Well, the data is available on every site and for everyone, actually. You just can't see it conveniently with less than 1000 reputation points - or this nice little [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/36420) ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes, this exists as a feature of all sites in the StackExchange system (to my knowledge), which includes StackOverflow and all the other StackExchange sites.

**HOWEVER, it's a privilege that you need to unlock on a per-site basis, by gaining rep on each individual site.**

You need [obtain and then *maintain* 1,000 or more reputation points to get that privilege](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/established-user).

According to your list of other accounts on your main profile page, only Ask Ubuntu is where you have over 1000 rep.  So you haven't unlocked the feature anywhere else.:

[image]

Comment: Ah... just as I thought! See I already made that edit. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @pomsky Nope, just accept the answer, or leave the question alone.  This is a valid question that even if you did delete I'd undelete as a "valid question" (and there's no need to delete the question really).